# im reatively new to coding and im facing a problem

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I'm new to competitive programming I have been trying to solve a question on code chef. when I tried on my dev c++ compiler I didn't get any error however I'm getting runtime error on online code chef IDE.

```
int main() {

    int n,q;
    int l,r;
    int *A;
    int *B;
    int *J;
    int *C;
    cin >> n >> q;
    A=new int[n];
    B=new int[n];
    J=new int[n];
    C=new int[q];
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        cin >> A[i];
    }
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        cin >> B[i];
    }
    J[0]=0;

    for (int j=1;j<n+1;j++) {
        J[j]=J[j-1]+(A[j-1]*B[j-1]);
    }

    for (int i=0;i<q;i++) {
        cin >> l >> r;
        if (r==1) {
            C[i]=J[1];
        }
        else {
            C[i]=J[r]-J[l-1];
        }

    }
    for(int i=0;i<q;i++){
        cout << C[i] << endl;
    }
    delete []A;
    delete []B;
    delete []C;
    delete []J;

    return 0;
}
```

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_array_new_length'

> ```
> what():  std::bad_array_new_length
> ```

Comment: Try printing the value for `n` and `q` to see if it make sense

Comment: you have for sure an access out of an array, some potential access out of array, and potential illegal allocation size, see my answer

Comment: I strongly advise against using DevC++, it's not properly developed and has a bundle of issues. If you need a free IDE there are plenty here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments#C/C++ that will more effectively meet your needs, of which I would personally recommend Code::Blocks, Eclipse, or Visual Studio.

Comment: Unrelated: Try to give your questions descriptive titles. It makes it easier for programmers who follow to find your question. Similarly, try to give your identifiers meaningful names. It makes it easier for everybody if the variables are named after what they contain or represent and functions named after what they do. Plus it is harder for typo in a a multi-letter identifier to slip through the compiler than if you accidentally use `A` where you meant to use `B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having

> ```
> cin >> n >> q;
> A=new int[n];
> B=new int[n];
> J=new int[n];
> C=new int[q];
> ```

you do check if you input valid sizes, not even something

> what():  std::bad_array_new_length

indicates the value of *n* and/or *q* is too large for the `new [n]` or `new[q]`. This is very probably the case if you input negative integers (the size are *unsigned*) , or can be the case if you do not input 2 valid integers so at least one the of vars is not initialized (undefined behavior), or of course if you enter at least a very large integer.

In a general way all `cin >> ...`, must be `if (!(cin >> ...)) { ...error management ... }`

So do at least :

```
if (!(cin >> n >> q) || (n < 1) || (q < 1)) {
  cerr << "invalid sizes" << endl;
  return -1;
}
```

---

Having

> ```
> J=new int[n];
> ...
> for(int j=1;j<n+1;j++){
>     J[j]=J[j-1]+(A[j-1]*B[j-1]);
>
> }
> ```

`J[j]` is `J[n]` at the last turn, so you write out of the allocated array

---

Also in

```
for(int i=0;i<q;i++){
    cin >> l >> r;
    if(r==1){
        C[i]=J[1];
    }
    else{

    C[i]=J[r]-J[l-1];
}
```

you do not check the value of *l* and *r* are valid indexes, nor if integer was given as input

`cin >> l >> r;` can be something like

```
if (!(cin >> l >> r) || 
    (r < 0) || (r >= n) ||
    (l < 1) || (l >= (n - 1))) {
  cerr << "invalid indexes" << endl;
  return -1;
}
```